# How do I use '.replaceWith' to load data from another html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

Trying to load data from my news page in my navigation menu using .load, .find and .replaceWidth but my javascript code does not fetch the data at all.  Can any developer tell me what I am doing wrong?

JAVASCRIPT FILE

```
jQuery('#latestnews').load('latest-news.html' + '.case a 
h2:first',function(data) {

jQuery('#latestnews').find('h2').replaceWith('');

});

jQuery('#headline').load('latest-news.html' + '.case a p:first',function(data) {

jQuery('#headline').find('span').replaceWith('');

});

jQuery('#newsimg').load('latest-news.html' + '.case a 
img:first',function(data) {

jQuery('#newsimg').find('img').replaceWith('');

});
```

HTML Navigation menu where I would like data to be fetched to.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu-items">
<li>
<div id="latestnews"><h2><!--Where the news data would go--></h2></div>
<a href="#" id="newsimg">
<div class="fll" id="headline">
<span><!--Where the news data would go--></span>
<p class="reserved">Read The Article</p>
</div>
<img src="assets/img/interactive-workshops.jpg" alt="Interactive Workshops" title="Interactive Workshops" width="" height="" class="flr">
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

HTML Code that needs fetching from my latest-news.html and to appear in navigation menu

```
<div class="case newsarticle">
<a href="#" target="_blank">
<img src="assets/img/latest-news.jpg" alt="" title="" width="326" height="245">
<h2>Content Title To Appear in Navigation Menu...</h2>
<p>Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content...</p>
<span>Read More</span>
</a>
</div>
```

The data just doesn't appear at all. If I remove the concatenation (' + ') between the 'latest-news.html' + '.case a h2:first' I still get the same response.

Comment: You are NOT loading the file `latest-news.html`. You are loading the file `latest-news.html.case a 
h2:first` because you are concatenating both strings with the `+` operator.

Comment: Thanks, how do I target a specific element on the latest-news.html within that javascript code?

Comment: jQuery.load supports a convension to load a fragment. Try to add a space before `.case`.

Comment: @ninhPham I have tried adding the space and also used a comma but I get the same issue.

Comment: Press F12 in the browser and check the "Network" tab for the `latest-news.html` request and if is loading properly. Also check the "Console" tab for any error. Also, how do you added the space?

Comment: Thanks for your help @jorge, I added to my code and seemed to get it all working.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my javascript file to this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#latestnews').load('latest-news.html .case a h2:first');
jQuery('#latestnews').find('h2').replaceWith('');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#headline').load('latest-news.html .case a p:first');
jQuery('#headline').find('p span').replaceWith('');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#newsimg').load('latest-news.html .case a img:first');
jQuery('#newsimg').find('img').replaceWith('');
});
```

and changed my HTML file to this:-

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu-items">
<li>
<div id="latestnews"><h2></h2></div>
<a href="#">
<div class="fll">
<div id="headline">
<p><span></span></p>
<p class="reserved">Read The Article</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="newsimg" class="flr">
<img src="assets/img/interactive-workshops.jpg" alt="Interactive Workshops" title="Interactive Workshops" width="" height="">
</div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am not sure if my Javascript is technically correct however I have managed to create the desired effect I was looking for.  Removing the 'function(data)' seemed to be the key.